# Initialize the first elememt of the structure or the whole structure?

Tags: c, gcc

all:
        In C language:

```
struct A  
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

A aa = {0};
```

This statement initialize aa.a only or initialize the whole struture? Or the behavior depends on Compiler?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the standard ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf))

> #### 6.7.9 Initialization
>
> ...
> 10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
> indeterminate. If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
> explicitly, then:
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
> and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
> — if it is a union, the ﬁrst named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
> rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
> ...
> 21 If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
> of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
> size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
> initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

So in your example `aa.a` would be explicitly initialized to 0 due to the initializer, while `aa.b` would be implicitly initialized to 0 because of the clauses above.

Answer (score 4):

```
One more ex:
struct A  
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct A aa = {5};
```

This will initialize the whole structure but aa.b will be initialized to 0.
If you initialize only few members of a structure then all other members of that will be automatically initialized to 0.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C99 standard, section 6.7.8.17, only the first member (in declaration order, i.e. the `a` field) is initialized explicitly in your example:

> Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated current object. When no designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according to the type of the current object: array elements in increasing subscript order, structure members in declaration order, and the first named member of a union.

By "designation" the standard means

```
A aa = {.b = 0};
```

This is a more precise way of letting programmers decide what fields get initialized.

Answer (score 1):

> This statement initialize aa.a only or initialize the whole struture?

Have a look at the example below , initializing the structure with {3} , is similar to initializing with {3,0}.

Hence in your program when you initialize with {0} , you are actually initializing both a and b (the whole structure) , with {0,0}

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct A  
{
    int a;
    int b;
}a;

int main()
{
a aa = {3};
printf("\na1 = %d",aa.a);
printf("\nb1 = %d",aa.b);

a bb = {3,0};
printf("\na2 = %d",bb.a);
printf("\nb2 = %d",bb.b);

}
```